# Java8: Findout which thread is creating the file

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

Every Thread in our application log output to separate file.
Lately we have noticed an issue where few threads hung up in between. While these threads hung, other threads are fine and it is creating new threads to finish other work. No dead locks noticed from thread dump.  No memory issues at this point.
I know the log file name for the hung threads. Just to trace the problem further, If I could find thread number of the Thread creating these log file, I can concentrate on that thread to investigate further.
Is there a way to find out which thread is using the given file resource? any other suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: How about letting each thread log its own ID right at the beginning?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Chances to any of them isn't allowed. So I am looking options to track without code change.

Comment: I’m afraid, the cause of a hanging thread will be a bug that can only be fixed by changing the code anyway. Unless the thread is directly hanging in a write method, there is no fixed association between threads and files—except for the one created by the application itself. You, resp. the developer of the application, should know how the thread knows or determines that this specific file is its own log file. That’s precisely the thing you have to look for, e.g. in a heap dump or live with a debugger, etc.

Comment: Either Heap Dump or Thread Dump provide any concerning information. Issue we have noticed doesnt happen all the time. It never happened on lower environment. When it happens in prod, there is no pattern. I am looking for a way to isolate the thread when it happens to investigate

Comment: Which raises the question, which ways to investigate are available in your production environment.

Comment: It run different category of jobs. If I could find out the associating to file, I would focus more on that category of jobs in my lower environment.

Comment: Since you said you now the responsible log file, does it not contain any hint on the job category?